# GoLang, REST, PATCH and building an UPDATE query

Tags: sql, rest, go, http-patch

since few days I was struggling on how to proceed with PATCH request in Go REST API until I have found an [article about using pointers and `omitempty` tag](https://willnorris.com/2014/05/go-rest-apis-and-pointers) which I have populated and is working fine. Fine until I have realized I still have to build an `UPDATE` SQL query.

My `struct` looks like this:

```
type Resource struct {
    Name        *string `json:"name,omitempty"        sql:"resource_id"`
    Description *string `json:"description,omitempty" sql:"description"`
}
```

I am expecting a `PATCH /resources/{resource-id}` request containing such a request body:

```
{"description":"Some new description"}
```

In my handler I will build the `Resource` object this way (ignoring imports, ignoring error handling):

```
var resource Resource
resourceID, _ := mux.Vars(r)["resource-id"]

d := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
d.Decode(&resource)

// at this point our resource object should only contain
// the Description field with the value from JSON in request body
```

Now, for normal `UPDATE` (`PUT` request) I would do this (simplified):

```
stmt, _ := db.Prepare(`UPDATE resources SET description = ?, name = ? WHERE resource_id = ?`)
res, _ := stmt.Exec(resource.Description, resource.Name, resourceID)
```

The problem with `PATCH` and `omitempty` tag is that the object might be missing multiple properties, thus I cannot just prepare a statement with hardcoded fields and placeholders... I will have to build it dynamically.

And here comes my question: **how can I build such `UPDATE` query dynamically?** In the best case I'd need some solution with identifying the set properties, getting their *SQL* field names (probably from the tags) and then I should be able to build the `UPDATE` query. I know I can use *reflection* to get the object properties but have no idea hot to get their *sql tag name* and of course I'd like to avoid using reflection here if possible... Or I could simply check for each property it is not `nil`, but in real life the structs are much bigger than provided example here...

Can somebody help me with this one? Did somebody already have to solve the same/similar situation?

**SOLUTION:**

Based on the answers here I was able to come up with this abstract solution. The `SQLPatches` method builds the `SQLPatch` struct from the given struct (so no concrete struct specific):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

const tagname = "sql"

type SQLPatch struct {
    Fields []string
    Args   []interface{}
}

func SQLPatches(resource interface{}) SQLPatch {
    var sqlPatch SQLPatch
    rType := reflect.TypeOf(resource)
    rVal := reflect.ValueOf(resource)
    n := rType.NumField()

    sqlPatch.Fields = make([]string, 0, n)
    sqlPatch.Args = make([]interface{}, 0, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fType := rType.Field(i)
        fVal := rVal.Field(i)
        tag := fType.Tag.Get(tagname)

        // skip nil properties (not going to be patched), skip unexported fields, skip fields to be skipped for SQL
        if fVal.IsNil() || fType.PkgPath != "" || tag == "-" {
            continue
        }

        // if no tag is set, use the field name
        if tag == "" {
            tag = fType.Name
        }
        // and make the tag lowercase in the end
        tag = strings.ToLower(tag)

        sqlPatch.Fields = append(sqlPatch.Fields, tag+" = ?")

        var val reflect.Value
        if fVal.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            val = fVal.Elem()
        } else {
            val = fVal
        }

        switch val.Kind() {
        case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
            sqlPatch.Args = append(sqlPatch.Args, val.Int())
        case reflect.String:
            sqlPatch.Args = append(sqlPatch.Args, val.String())
        case reflect.Bool:
            if val.Bool() {
                sqlPatch.Args = append(sqlPatch.Args, 1)
            } else {
                sqlPatch.Args = append(sqlPatch.Args, 0)
            }
        }
    }

    return sqlPatch
}
```

Then I can simply call it like this:

```
type Resource struct {
    Description *string `json:"description,omitempty"`
    Name *string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var r Resource

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"description": "new description"}`), &r)
    sqlPatch := SQLPatches(r)

    data, _ := json.Marshal(sqlPatch)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
}
```

You can check it at [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TdwAhb7pjT). The only problem here I see is that I allocate both the slices with the amount of fields in the passed struct, which may be 10, even though I might only want to patch one property in the end resulting in allocating more memory than needed... **Any idea how to avoid this?**

Comment: So, it is 2021. Is there any better solution for the task?

Comment: @GHopper Hello and thanks for a comment. I added my own answer here, there you can find answer to your question as well :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I think the solution I used back in 2016 was quite over-engineered for even more over-engineered problem and was completely unnecessary. The question asked here was very generalized, however we were building a solution that was able to build its SQL query on its own and based on the JSON object or query parameters and/or Headers sent in the request. And that to be as generic as possible.

Nowadays I think the best solution is to avoid PATCH unless truly necessary. And even then you still can use PUT and replace the whole resource with patched property/ies coming already from the client - i.e. not giving the client the option/possibility to send any PATCH request to your server and to deal with *partial updates* on their own.

However this is not always recommended, especially in cases of *bigger* objects to save some C0<sup>2</sup> by reducing the amount of redundant transmitted data. Whenever today if I need to enable a PATCH for the client I simply define what can be patched - this gives me clarity and the final struct.

*Note that I am using a [IETF documented](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7396) **JSON Merge Patch** implementation. I consider that of `JSON Patch` (also [documented by IETF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902)) redundant as hypothetically we could replace the whole REST API by having one single `JSON Patch` endpoint and let clients control the resources via allowed operations. I also think the implementation of such `JSON Patch` on the server side is way more complicated. The only use-case I could think of using such implementation is if I was implementing a REST API over a file system...*

So the struct may be defined as in my OP:

```go
    type ResourcePatch struct {
        ResourceID  some.UUID `json:"resource_id"`
        Description *string `json:"description,omitempty"`
        Name        *string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    }
```

In the handler func I'd decode the ID from the path into the ResourcePatch instance and unmarshall JSON from the request body into it, too.

Sending only this

```
{"description":"Some new description"}
```

to `PATCH /resources/<UUID>`

I should end up with with this object:

```
ResourcePatch
    * ResourceID {"UUID"}
    * Description {"Some new description"}
```

And now the magic: use a simple logic to build the query and exec parameters. For some it may seem tedious or repetitive or unclean for *bigger PATCH objects*, but my reply to this would be: **if your PATCH object consists of more than 50% of the original resource' properties** (or simply too many for your liking) **use PUT and expect the clients to send (and replace) the whole resource instead**.

It could look like this:

```go
    func (s Store) patchMyResource(r models.ResourcePatch) error {
        q := `UPDATE resources SET `
        qParts := make([]string, 0, 2)
        args := make([]interface{}, 0, 2)

        if r.Description != nil {
            qParts = append(qParts, `description = ?`)
            args = append(args, r.Description)
        }

        if r.Name != nil {
            qParts = append(qParts, `name = ?`)
            args = append(args, r.Name)
        }

        q += strings.Join(qParts, ',') + ` WHERE resource_id = ?`
        args = append(args, r.ResourceID)

        _, err := s.db.Exec(q, args...)

        return err
    }
```

I think there's nothing simpler and more effective. No reflection, no over-kills, reads quite good.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had same problem. about PATCH and looking around found [this article](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). It also makes references to the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) where it says:

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource identified by the Request-URI. In a PUT request, the enclosed entity is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be replaced. **With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains *a set of instructions* describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version.** The PATCH method affects the resource identified by the Request-URI, and it also MAY have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a PATCH.

e.g:

```
[
    { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
    { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
    { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
    { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
    { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
]
```

This set of instructions should make it easier to build the update query.

**EDIT**

This is how you would [obtain sql tags](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag) but you will have to use reflection:

```
type Resource struct {
        Name        *string `json:"name,omitempty"        sql:"resource_id"`
        Description *string `json:"description,omitempty" sql:"description"`
}

sp := "sort of string"
r := Resource{Description: &sp}
rt := reflect.TypeOf(r) // reflect.Type
rv := reflect.ValueOf(r) // reflect.Value

for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ { // Iterate over all the fields
    if !rv.Field(i).IsNil() { // Check it is not nil

        // Here you would do what you want to having the sql tag.
        // Creating the query would be easy, however
        // not sure you would execute the statement

        fmt.Println(rt.Field(i).Tag.Get("sql")) // Output: description
    }
}
```

I understand you don't want to use reflection, but still this may be a better answer than the previous one as you comment state.

**EDIT 2:**

About the allocation - read this guide lines of Effective Go about [Data structures and Allocation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#data):

```
// Here you are allocating an slice of 0 length with a capacity of n
sqlPatch.Fields = make([]string, 0, n)
sqlPatch.Args = make([]interface{}, 0, n)
```

With `make(Type, Length, Capacity (optional))`

Consider the following example:

```
// newly allocated zeroed value with Composite Literal 
// length: 0
// capacity: 0
testSlice := []int{}
fmt.Println(len(testSlice), cap(testSlice)) // 0 0
fmt.Println(testSlice) // []

// newly allocated non zeroed value with make   
// length: 0
// capacity: 10
testSlice = make([]int, 0, 10)
fmt.Println(len(testSlice), cap(testSlice)) // 0 10
fmt.Println(testSlice) // []

// newly allocated non zeroed value with make   
// length: 2
// capacity: 4
testSlice = make([]int, 2, 4)
fmt.Println(len(testSlice), cap(testSlice)) // 2 4
fmt.Println(testSlice) // [0 0]
```

In your case, may want to the following:

```
// Replace this
sqlPatch.Fields = make([]string, 0, n)
sqlPatch.Args = make([]interface{}, 0, n)

// With this or simple omit the capacity in make above
sqlPatch.Fields = []string{}
sqlPatch.Args = []interface{}{}

// The allocation will go as follow: length - capacity
testSlice := []int{} // 0 - 0
testSlice = append(testSlice, 1) // 1 - 2
testSlice = append(testSlice, 1) // 2 - 2   
testSlice = append(testSlice, 1) // 3 - 4   
testSlice = append(testSlice, 1) // 4 - 4   
testSlice = append(testSlice, 1) // 5 - 8
```

Comment: I have read this article already. In our case the PATCH will always only **replace** the provided set of properties thus I have decided to omit the redundant properties from request body considering the `{property:value}` should be enough. RFC is not specific on how should the `[description of changes]` look like thus I cannot believe anybody saying *this way is bad* or *this way only is correct*. Nevertheless, your answer doesn't help to solve my problem at all.

Comment: @shadyyx , I updated the answer, this would give you a notion, but it uses reflection

Comment: @shadyyx Updated the answer regarding to your allocation concern

Answer (score 3):

Struct tags are only visible through reflection, sorry.

If you don't want to use reflection (or, I think, even if you do), I think it is Go-like to define a function or method that "marshals" your struct into something that can easily be turned into a comma-separated list of SQL updates, and then use that. Build small things to help solve your problems.

For example given:

```
type Resource struct {
    Name        *string `json:"name,omitempty"        sql:"resource_id"`
    Description *string `json:"description,omitempty" sql:"description"`
}
```

You might define:

```
func (r Resource) SQLUpdates() SQLUpdates {
    var s SQLUpdates
    if (r.Name != nil) {
        s.add("resource_id", *r.Name)
    }
    if (r.Description != nil) {
        s.add("description", *r.Description)
    }
}
```

where the type SQLUpdates looks something like this:

```
type SQLUpdates struct {
    assignments []string
    values []interface{}
}
func (s *SQLUpdates) add(key string, value interface{}) {
    if (s.assignments == nil) {
        s.assignments = make([]string, 0, 1)
    }
    if (s.values == nil) {
        s.values = make([]interface{}, 0, 1)
    }
    s.assignments = append(s.assignments, fmt.Sprintf("%s = ?", key))
    s.values = append(s.values, value)
}
func (s SQLUpdates) Assignments() string {
    return strings.Join(s.assignments, ", ")
}
func (s SQLUpdates) Values() []interface{} {
    return s.values
}
```

See it working (sorta) here: https://play.golang.org/p/IQAHgqfBRh

If you have deep structs-within-structs, it should be fairly easy to build on this. And if you change to an SQL engine that allows or encourages positional arguments like `$1` instead of `?`, it's easy to add that behavior to just the `SQLUpdates` struct without changing any code that used it.

For the purpose of getting arguments to pass to `Exec`, you would just expand the output of `Values()` with the `...` operator.

Comment: Of course you could also add `if value == nil { return; }` to the top of `SQLUpdates.add()` and then you'd generally be able to write your "marshalling" methods as just a sequence of calls to `add()`.

Comment: This is basically identical with what I have came up yesterday after posting this question during waiting for the answers :-) Your answer's code is more structured than what I have done, though, and I like it! I'll restructure it little bit to suit our projects structure and accept the answer after it is all working fine! Thanks!

Comment: Pls, check my added solution and my final question :-) Thanks BTW!